# Express and Webpack Problem: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I am having trouble testing out my react webpage I developed using WebPack. I am attempting to run an express server and I keep getting a blank localhost page with the console message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. It appears the webpage is able to find my index.html file which in turn points it to the bundle.js file created by webpack, but for some reason my bundle.js file comes up empty I believe? This is my first time using webpack so I am still relatively new to this. I will post pictures/snippets below of my directory structure, `webpack.config.js` file, `server.js` file, and `index.html` file. Thank you so much in advance, again I am new to webpack and this is my first time trying to actually deploy using express with webpack. **my react app has worked fine running using `webpack-dev-server` by the way, so it is not that.**

### My Directory Structure

[directory-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SbkZ.png)

### My `webpack.config.js` file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill','./src/index.js'],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,  
            use: [{
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: { 
                    limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
                    name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
                } 
            }]
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new MomentLocalesPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  }
};
```

### My `server.js` file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname));


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on port ' + port);
    console.log(__dirname);
});
```

### My `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Webpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app'></div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### The Dev Tools Network Results

[chrome dev tools network results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RCMU.png)

### EDIT

My `server.js` file is now edited as displayed below. I have gotten past the first error, but now it is not able to find my bundle.js file? I will post picture of logging error from my git bash terminal below. The Chrome Dev Tools console is also giving me a 404 Error.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    if (req.path.endsWith('bundle.js')) {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundle.js'));
    } else {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
    }
});




/*
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
*/

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on port ' + port);
    console.log(__dirname);
});
```

[logging error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0flD0.png)

**Thank you so much!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server.js is serving `index.html` to all requests.

This means when the browser requests `bundle.js`, the server.js returns `index.html` once again. The error comes from the browser trying to parse the received HTML as JavaScript code.

## Fixing

Your `bundle.js` is probably not at the same folder of `index.html`, otherwise express would serve it (because of the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname));`).

So double check the path of your `bundle.js` is located. It should be at `__dirname` (namely `${__dirname}/bundle.js`).

From the picture you posted, [there is no `bundle.js` in the `dist/` folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SbkZ.png) where `index.html` and `server.js` are located.

#### Generating the bundle.js

You must generate the bundle. You say, [from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58090054/express-and-webpack-problem-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token/58090190#comment102573472_58090190), that your `scripts` are:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development", 
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

To generate the bundle, then, you should add a `build` script and execute it.

Add this to your package.json `scripts`:

```
"build": "webpack --mode production",
```

So it now is something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --mode production",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development", 
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

Now run `npm run build` (or `yarn build`). The `build.js` should now be in the `dist/` folder.

Remember that if you ever deploy it, you should take both `index.html` and `bundle.js` in the same folder when you serve it.

Comment: Hey thank you for the response! I just tried that, and it gave me a 404 error in the console, and another error in my git bash terminal. I will edit and post the picture above in my question. Do you by any chance know why it is doing so?

Comment: I have updated the answer. You should generate the `bundle.js` file and place it at `dist/` before running `server.js`.

Comment: How do I generate the bundle.js file? I always though webpack does that automatically. Sorry, I sound ignorant I know.

Comment: No, you don't sound ignorant at all. Did you create the app using `create-react-app`? Btw, you should restore your `server.js` to its original content (remove the `if (req.path.endsWith('bundle.js')) {` I suggested, though it would work, your original code was fine).

Comment: No I did not use create-react-app, I did it manually following an online tutorial at `https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup`. And I will restore that, thanks! I think my `webpack.config.js` file is supposed to create a `bundle.js` file inside my `dist/` folder.

Comment: Can you post the `scripts` part of your `package.json`?

Comment: `"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },`

Comment: Hmm, I checked out the tutorial and, if I looked right, you should run `npm run build` (or `yarn build`) and it should generate the `dist/bundle.js`

Comment: Wait, I see you don't have the `build` target script. You'll have to add one (my last comment's instructions will not work until you add it), give me a minute.

Comment: Okay thank you! Maybe you can answer this, once I run the build script, is there no going back? Because my app is not ready for deployment, I was just testing and making sure I could deploy to Heroku if I ever needed too.

Comment: Thank you acdcjunior, do you know if there is no going back once I run the build script? Or is it something I can do anytime I am ready to deploy for testing? --edit-- also I see that you are specifying `build.js` in your edit, do you mean `bundle.js`?

Comment: Hm.. I don't know what do you mean by "no going back", but you do can delete the `bundle.js` any time and execute `build` any time you wish. In fact, that's something you *must*  do to generate a new version (when you make changes to the code) so you can deploy it.

Comment: Okay I understand, I just wasn't sure if that configured all of my code and did not allow me to make changes easily anymore, or something along those lines. Adding that right now, I will let you know in a minute.

Comment: JSYK, this is the source for the `build` script I suggested: https://github.com/rwieruch/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup/issues/10#issue-335077446

Comment: It worked MY DAWG. Thanks so much. So anytime I need to make changes and deploy to, say heroku for example, I need to delete the current `bundle.js` and run `npm run build` again? --edit-- I am going to deploy to heroku now to fully test

Comment: Yes. Strictly speaking, you shouldn't need to delete it before running `build`, because the script should overwrite `build.js` anyway. But you can delete it, ofc 

Comment: Hey sorry to keep bothering you lol. But I don't know if you have ever used heroku, but I was able to succesfully deploy my build to heroku, except now when I try to visit the website, it is having trouble running it. Was I supposed to change something else in my package.json, like the npm start for example? --edit-- I believe when heroku tries to start a webpage, it uses `npm start`, maybe I need to change my start script?

Comment: What you deploy to heroku is a server-side (node) project. If you are deploying that react project directly to heroku, maybe you should rename your start script to `dev` and add a new start script along the lines of `"start": "npm run build && node ./dist/server.js"`